# Switching Lastname, Firstname in Powershell AD script

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, active-directory

I try to export AD groups and users from a OU by Firstname, Lastname but I only get it to work with Lastname, Firstname.

Everything else I try gives me an empty string for members.I tried changing the line under Select-Object to:

`@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.FirstName = GetFirstName $_.Name $_.LastName = GetLastName $_.Name}},`

```
$firt = $_.firstname
$last = $_.lastname
@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.name = "$first,$last"}},
```

This is the working code, but the names should be switched around.

```
$OU = 'OU=Groups,OU=City,OU=Continent,DC=DomainControler, DC=Domain, DC=net' #Change this to get different groups
$DateTime = Get-Date -f "dd-MM-yyyy" 

$MyFileName = "CompanyName-Groups_"+$DateTime+".csv"
$Path = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $MyFileName

$Groups =  get-adobject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "group"' -SearchBase $OU
$i=0
$tot = $Groups.count
$Data = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $i++ 
    $status = "{0:N0}" -f ($i / $tot * 100) 
    Write-Progress -Activity "Exporting AD Groups" -status "Processing Group $i of $tot : $status% Completed" -PercentComplete ($i / $tot * 100) 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | 
    Select-Object @{Name='Group';Expression={$Group.Name}}, 
                  @{Name='Member';Expression={$_.Name}}, 
                  @{Name='Enabled';Expression={if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {Get-ADUser $_ | Select-Object -Expand Enabled} else {'NA/Group'}}}
    }
$Data | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

This is an example output:

```
Group, "member", enabled
Admin, "Mario, Speedwagon", True
Admin, "Petey, Cruiser", True
Admin, "Anna, Sthesia", False
HR, "Paul, Molive", True
HR, "Phaedra, Lugt", True
IT, "Paul, Molive", False
IT, "Cliff, Hanger", True
```

This is what it should become:

```
Group, "member", enabled
Admin, "Speedwagon, Mario", True
Admin, "Cruiser, Petey", True
Admin, "Sthesia, Anna", False
HR, "Molive, Paul", True
HR, "Lugt, Phaedra", True
IT, "Molive, Paul", False
IT, "Hanger, Cliff", True
```

Comment: what are `GetFirstName` & `GetLastName`? where did they come from? ///// you are calling `Get-ADUser` in the `Enabled` section ... so why don't you use that as your source for `GivenName` & `Surname`?

Comment: After I export the .csv I split by `,` in Excel and put the data into a Pivot table. The `Enabled`  section gives me the option to filter accounts by enabled or disabled. even `@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.GivenName}}` gives me an empty string for members.

Comment: that will not work since the `$_` holds the current pipeline object ... which does not appear to contain a `.GivenName` property. [*grin*] you need to call `Get-ADUser` to obtain that.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying now, I need to call `Get-ADuser` within `Select-Object @{Name='Member'}` I still get an empty string like that though. At least I know what I'm doing wrong now!

Comment: glad to know that you are on track ... [*grin*]

Comment: Please check out my answer, it contains `CombinedName` that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Better put the order right 1st place, to reverse afterwars you can split, reorder the index and join again i.e. `("Mario, Speedwagon" -split ', ')[1,0] -join ', '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might clear things up for you:

```
$OU = 'OU=Groups,OU=City,OU=Continent,DC=DomainControler, DC=Domain, DC=net'

$PathParams = @{
    Path      = $PSScriptRoot
    ChildPath = "PA-AD-Groups_{0}.csv" -f (Get-Date -f "dd-MM-yyyy")
}
$FilePath = Join-Path @PathParams

$Groups = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "group"' -SearchBase $OU
$i = 0
$tot = $Groups.count

$Data = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $i++
    $ProgressParams = @{
        Activity        = 'Exporting AD Groups'
        PercentComplete = ($i / $tot * 100)
        status          = "Processing Group $i of $tot : {0:N0} Completed" -f
        ($i / $tot * 100)
    }
    Write-Progress @ProgressParams

    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
        Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$Group.Name}},
    @{Name = 'Member'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
    @{Name = 'Enabled'; Expression = {
            $Script:User = $false
            if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
                $Script:User = Get-ADUser $_
                if ($User.Enabled) {$true} else {$false}
            }
            else {
                'NA/Group'
            }
        }
    },
    @{Name = 'FirstName'; Expression = {
            if ($User) {
                $User.GivenName
            }
        }
    },
    @{Name = 'LastName'; Expression = {
            if ($User) {
                $User.Surname
            }
        }
    },
    @{Name = 'CombinedName'; Expression = {
            if ($User) {
               "{0}, {1}" -f $User.GivenName, $User.Surname
            }
        }
    }
}

$Data | Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

The issue you have is that you can't use the properties from `$User` outside of the `Expression` within the `Select-Object`. This is simply fixed by creating a variable that is available throughout the script and as such is called `Script scope`, used as `$Script:User`.

More info can be found in `Get-Help about_Scopes` or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

On a side note I would advice you to use proper indentation, it makes things more readable. The splatted parameter `hashtable` helps in this regard too. As a last tip: don't create a variable if you only use it once. Otherwise it just confuses you later on.

Comment: Thanks for the the detailed reply, as you can maybe see I'm quite new to Powershell. I found most of this code on the internet. I'm also taking a course from 0. The output from your code gives me a very strange output so I edited the first post with what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to change the values within `member` not `enabled`

Comment: Simply remove the `Select-Object` pieces you don't need and rename the `Name` to your liking. Remove `Member`, rename `CombinedName` to member, ...

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot for taking the time mate! You saved me a lot of manual input!